# Error Unknown command '\U' when restoring MySQL dump on Windows

Tags: mysql, mariadb, restore, mysqldump

I am updating software that used MySQL 5.4.3 in its old version, and now uses MariaDB 10.2.11.
So, I dumped the old data with that command:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --no-create-info --skip-triggers --complete-insert theDBName -r C:\Users\myUserName\theDBName_data.dump
```

Then I uninstalled MySQL and replaced it by MariaDB. After that I created the database and imported the new data structure (a few columns have been added with default values).

The issue occurs when restoring the old data:

```
mysql -uroot -p --default-character-set=utf8 theDBName
Enter password: ****************

MariaDB [theDBName]> SET names 'utf8';
MariaDB [theDBName]> SOURCE C:\Users\myUserName\theDBName_data.dump
ERROR: Unknown command '\U'.
ERROR: Unknown command '\a'
ERROR: Unknown command '\a'
ERROR: Failed to open file 'C:\Users\myUserName\theDBName_data.dump', error: 2
```

Restoring the exact same dump with that procedure works well on Linux, but doesn't on Windows.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Version MySQL 5.4.3 never existed.  Please check again.  Perhaps you meant MariaDB 5.4.3?

Comment: mysql -V result : mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.4.3-beta, for Win32 (ia32)

Comment: The publisher has delivered to its customers its software with a beta version of mysql...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> MariaDB [theDBName]> SOURCE C:\Users\myUserName\theDBName_data.dump

Either of the following should be correct:

```
MariaDB [theDBName]> SOURCE C:\\Users\\myUserName\\theDBName_data.dump

MariaDB [theDBName]> SOURCE C:/Users/myUserName/theDBName_data.dump
```

Comment: Oh, I really did not think about it, and yet it's a common problem... The first solution doesn't work (ERROR: Unknown command '\\'), but the second works as intended. Thank you.